# как разделить выборку на 3 проверочных датасета?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, выборка

У меня есть [папка для проверки нейронной сети](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V0P9VIMZZwmjRr335WUkhl2ViiXhtzXM?usp=sharing), я хочу ее разбить на три выборки для сети, чтобы проверить, как часто [нейронная сеть](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1by8xQwBw_IsSBQRCB7xCICyc1c9HHmLM?usp=sharing) ошибается на каждом классе.
Как я загружал данные в обучающую модель:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=15, width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.1, horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode='nearest', validation_split=0.1)
train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True, subset='training')
validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True, subset='validation')
```

Как я проверял модель:

```py
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/БД/распознавание 3 марок машин/данные/Автомобили/val/'
validation = datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(img_height, img_width), batch_size=batch_size, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=True, subset='validation')
answers = model.evaluate(validation, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Но как мне проверить модель на каждом классе отдельно?

Comment: Если получается как в последнем блоке, так и проверяйте, указывая папку, она же через папки работает, наборы данных видимо не получится разделить это ведь не матрица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, и "класс" -  это выход, т.е. результат работы вашей нейромодели то просто проверяете работу построенной модели и считаете не только "угадала" ли она или нет, но и делаете это отдельно по каждому "классу", сравнивая полученную метку с имеющейся.  И, кстати, вы надеюсь, знаете, что учить модель на данных только одного класса -  нельзя.

А вот зачем вы делите данные на три датасета -  непонятно. Обычно работают с двумя - учебной и тестовой выборками. Третья может появиться разве что если вы делаете кросс-валидацию.

Comment: Нет, ну 3 выборки тоже бывает. Первая учебная, вторая валидационная - с помощью неё подбирают гиперпараметры и т.д., при обучении нейросетей её можно указать модели, чтобы она сразу с валидационной выборкой сверялась в процессе обучения и могла что-то поменять в обучении, если что-то пойдёт совсем не так, а третья используется уже в самом конце для проверки того, насколько модель хорошо предскажет не виденные ей данные в уже полностью обученном виде.